# How do I set a breakpoint inside an included aspx file?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an aspx file which contains VB.NET code (and a little markup) and is included in other files like so:

```
<!-- #include file="MyFile.aspx" -->
```

(this is legacy code, I would put the code in a module or class if it were up to me, it is convenient not having to rebuild the solution to run the latest code, though!)

However when I set a breakpoint inside MyFile.aspx, I get this message:

> The breakpoint will not be hit. No symbols are currently loaded for this document.

Is there any way to set a breakpoint in an included aspx file and actually have it get hit?

Comment: Breakpoints in an ASPX can be tricky. The easiest way, without messing about with IIS configuration, is to call `Debugger.Break();`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debugger.break?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Thanks! Just out of curiosity, what IIS configuration would I need to mess with? if I could set this up once it would be well worth it...